# Angular typescript: dynamically create associative array

Tags: angular, typescript, associative-array

I have an interface graph:

```
export interface Graph {
shows: number,
clicks: number,
leads: number,
payouts: number,
sales: number,
wages: number,
profit: number,
N_CPM: number,
our_CPM: number,
visits: number,
ROI: number,
bidfloor: number
```

}

I have the associative array like this: `platData: {[key: string] : {[key: string]: Graph}} = {}`

I have the double loop that iterates through arrays of platforms (plat) and dates (date)

Inside the loops I try to define Graphs: `this.platData[plat][date] = {shows: 0, wages: 0, sales: 0, payouts: 0, leads: 0, clicks: 0, profit: 0, visits: 0, ROI: 0, N_CPM: 0, our_CPM: 0, bidfloor: 0 }`

After running I have this error: `TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '2022-07-07')`

How can I solve it?

I tried doing like that: `this.platData[plat] = {date: {shows: 0, wages: 0, sales: 0, payouts: 0, leads: 0, clicks: 0, profit: 0, visits: 0, ROI: 0, N_CPM: 0, our_CPM: 0, bidfloor: 0 }}`

It runs but date here is read as literal string and not as a string variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to use the `date` as a variable key.

```
this.platData[plat] = {
  [date]: {
    shows: 0,
    wages: 0,
    sales: 0,
    payouts: 0,
    leads: 0,
    clicks: 0,
    profit: 0,
    visits: 0,
    ROI: 0,
    N_CPM: 0,
    our_CPM: 0,
    bidfloor: 0
  }
};
```

Note the square brackets around `date`. This makes it use the value of the variable `date`, rather than the literal string.